# shell_exec() does not output the right values

Tags: php, laravel, shell, pdftotext

I'm trying to build a simple diagostic endpoint in Laravel to know what versions of software is installed on the queried machine. In this sense I have these lines of code with the corresponding outputs:

```
dump(shell_exec('pdftotext -v')); // null

exec('pdftotext -v', $output, $code);
dump($output, $code); // [], 0
```

But if I simply write the same thing in the terminal this works well:

```
> pdftohtml -v
pdftohtml version 21.12.0
```

Or even:

```
> php -r 'shell_exec("pdftotext -v");'
pdftohtml version 21.12.0
```

So then why is this difference and why can't I run the same thing from PHP?

Same behaviour on OSX locally and on a production Vapor environment.

Comment: Are you executing as different users?

Comment: I tried whoami on both places to be sure, it's the same user

Answer (score 0):

taken from the php_manual site

If you're trying to run a command such as "gunzip -t" in shell_exec and getting an empty result, you might need to add 2>&1 to the end of the command, eg:

Won't always work:

```
echo shell_exec("gunzip -c -t $path_to_backup_file");
```

Should work:

```
echo shell_exec("gunzip -c -t $path_to_backup_file 2>&1");
```